# Accessing files on network drive using WAMP and PHP

Tags: php, apache, laravel, wamp, network-drive

I am trying to access files on a network drive using PHP and WAMP but I am experiencing difficulty.

Here is some information pertaining to have I have tried:

- Mapped to: U:
- UNC: \\ECHO

I have tried the following in many variations (with share name, with share name and text file) here are some:

```
$h = opendir('\\\\ip address'); error: opendir(\\ip address,\\ip address): The specified path is invalid. (code: 161)

$h = opendir('\\ip address'); error: opendir(\ip address,\ip address): The specified path is invalid. (code: 161)

$h = opendir('U:/'); error: opendir(U:/,U:/): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

$h = opendir('U:/Share Name'); (the share name contains a space)  error: opendir(U:/Share Name,U:/Share Nane): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

$h = is_dir("\\\\ECHO"); error: opendir(\\ECHO,\\ECHO): The specified path is invalid. (code: 161)

$h = opendir("\\ECHO");opendir(\ECHO,\ECHO): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

$h = opendir("\\ECHO\\Share Name\\test.txt"); opendir(\ECHO\Share Name\test.txt,\ECHO\Share Name\test.txt): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)
```

This is with wampapache64 logged on as the Local System account. If I change wampapache64's log on credentials to my user credentials the same messages occur.

My user account can add/delete/modify files from the network drive as well as my network drive share.

This problem has me stumped and I am not sure what else to do. Any suggestions?